# Banach Algebras in the context of commutative algebra

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, banach-algebras

Banach algebras are primarily studied within the context of functional analysis.

Is there any theory attempting to study commutative Banach algebras from the viewpoint of commutative algebra?

Comment: Infinite-dimensional commutative Banach algebras are rarely (maybe never?) Noetherian, so a lot of the usual machinery of commutative algebra is inapplicable.